# ExecuteNonQuery() doesn't updating correctly

Tags: c#

I would like to update all 2 field records as long as one condition is satisfied. One of the fields is being updated correctly ([Valor] = @sValor). The problem is that the second field ([ValorporPeca] = @sValorPorPeca) is always updated with the value from the last calculated record.

My procedures are listed below:

```
private void BtnGravarPreco_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<SQLParametro> param;
        GerirDB gerir;
        bool erro = true;

        try
        {
            gerir = new GerirDB();
            //List<decimal> dValorPorPeca = new List<decimal>();
            decimal quant, valor, dValorPorPeca;

            valor = decimal.Parse(ktbValor.Text.Replace("R$", "").Trim());

            const string querySelect = "SELECT * FROM Artesanato WHERE [Material] = @material";

            param = new List<SQLParametro>
            {
                new SQLParametro("@material", kwlMaterial.Text)
            };

            using (DataTable dados = gerir.ExeReader(querySelect, param))
            {
                if (dados.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow linha in dados.Rows)
                    {
                        gerir = new GerirDB();
                        quant = decimal.Parse(linha["Quantidade"].ToString());
                        dValorPorPeca = (valor * quant);
                        //dValorPorPeca.Add(valor * quant);

                        const string queryUpdate2 = "UPDATE Artesanato SET [Valor] = @sValor, [ValorporPeca] = @sValorPorPeca WHERE [Material] = @sMaterial";

                        param = new List<SQLParametro>
                        {
                            new SQLParametro("@sMaterial", kwlMaterial.Text),
                            new SQLParametro("@sValor", ktbValor.Text),
                            new SQLParametro("@sValorPorPeca", dValorPorPeca.ToString("C2"))
                        };

                        gerir = new GerirDB();
                        erro = gerir.ExeNonReader(queryUpdate2, param);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MsgBox.Show("Erro:\n" + ex.Message, "Banco de Dados - Artesanato", TipoIcone.Erro);
        }

        if (!erro)
            MsgBox.Show("Registros atualizados com sucesso!");

        BtnRetornar2_Click(btnRetornar2, KeyEventArgs.Empty);
    }

public DataTable ExeReader(string query, List<SQLParametro> parametros)
    {
        adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(query, ligacao);
        using (DataTable dados = new DataTable())
        {
            //Parâmetros
            adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            foreach (SQLParametro param in parametros)
            {
                adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.Parametro, param.Valor);
            }

            try
            {
                adaptador.Fill(dados);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MsgBox.Show("Erro:\n" + ex.Message, "ERRO", MsgBox.TipoIcone.Erro);
            }
            finally
            {
                adaptador.Dispose();
            }

            return dados;
        }
    }


public bool ExeNonReader(string query, List<SQLParametro> parametros)
    {
        bool Error = false;

        comando = new SqlCommand(query);

        //Parâmetros
        comando.Parameters.Clear();
        foreach (SQLParametro param in parametros)
        {
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.Parametro, param.Valor);
        }

        ligacao.Open();

        comando.Connection = ligacao;

        try
        {
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Error = false;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MsgBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERRO", MsgBox.TipoIcone.Erro);
            Error = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            ligacao.Dispose();
        }
        return Error;
    }

public class SQLParametro
    {
        public string Parametro { get; set; }
        public object Valor { get; set; }
        
        public SQLParametro(string param, object value)
        {
            Parametro = param;
            Valor = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're using the same values for `sMaterial` (`kwlMaterial.Text`) and `sValor` (`ktbValor.Text`) for each record - but I'm  not following the logic to know if that's intended. Run it in the debugger and set a breakpoint after the parameter values are set to see if their values are what you expect.

Comment: And why the custom parameter class (`SQLParametro`) instead of the built-in `SqlParameter` class? Seems like you're copying things around unnecessarily.

Comment: After the condition is satisfied all materials (@sMaterial) and all values (@sValor) must be the same throughout the table. This is working correctly. I've already used debug (breakpoint) and the program is working correctly. The problem is with the ValorporPeca field (@sValorPorPeca), which is sending the same value to all ValorporPeca fields.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upload any images due to the limitation of my account being new.

Comment: Are you saying `dValorPorPeca` is correct, but the parameter `@sValorPorPeca` isn't?  When you use the breakpoint, look at the values of valor and quant and see if they make sense.

Comment: Yes. And they all make sense. (dValorPorPeca) is calculated correctly, however, only the last calculation is carried out in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I just changed a few code lines.

```
using (DataTable dados = gerir.ExeReader(querySelect, param))
            {
                if (dados.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow linha in dados.Rows)
                    {
                        gerir = new GerirDB();
                        quant = decimal.Parse(linha["Quantidade"].ToString());
                        idArtesanato = int.Parse(linha["idArtesanato"].ToString());
                        dValorPorPeca = (valor * quant);

                        string queryUpdate2 = string.Format("UPDATE Artesanato SET [Valor] = @sValor, [ValorporPeca] = @sValorPorPeca WHERE [idArtesanato] = {0}", idArtesanato);

                        param = new List<SQLParametro>
                        {
                            new SQLParametro("@sValor", ktbValor.Text),
                            new SQLParametro("@sValorPorPeca", dValorPorPeca.ToString("C2"))
                        };

                        gerir = new GerirDB();
                        erro = gerir.ExeNonReader(queryUpdate2, param);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You don't need the `if (dados.Rows.Count != 0) {...}`.  If `dados.Rows` is empty, the for-each will just skip that block.